# rails 3: difference between write_attribute and update_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I did not know about write_attribute until today...

it seems like update_attribute, although not calling validation is still calling the :before_save callbacks, whereas write_attribute doesn't.

Is that the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`update_attribute` actually makes a physical call to the DB. You get a full execution of an `UPDATE` statement. It's like `update_attributes` but just for a single column.

While `write_attribute` writes the attribute for assignment to the model for AR based columns. If you were to overwrite a DB based attribute.

```
def first_name=(val)
  write_attribute :first_name, val
end
# some_model.first_name => 'whatever val is'

def first_name=(val)
  @first_name = val
end
# some_model.first_name => nil
```

I have not looked into `write_attribute` extensively, but I gather Activerecord based models handle assignments to db based columns slightly differently than your run of the mill accessor.

Answer (score 12):

`write_attribute` is used when you want to overwrite the default accessors for a method. It is essentially syntactic sugar for `self[:attribute]=(value)`.

Have a look at the [ActiveRecord::Base documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)under the heading "Overwriting default accessors".

If you tried to rewrite the example in the documentation using `update_attribute`, I'd imagine it would end up in a loop.